# Restsharp does not know when the other party cuts off the internet

Tags: c#, .net, restsharp

I have an application that consumes a REST API running on an Android device.

One test that I have to do, is to cut the smartphone Wi-Fi while in the middle of a request, but Restsharp never react and doesn't show any kind of error.

After the smartphone recover internet, restsharp never receives the response and it finally moves on timeout.

How can I make resthsarp react after server where I'm connected loses internet?

This is the code:

```
public RestInterface(string ip, string port)
{
    var baseUrl = string.Format("https://{0}:{1}/", ip, port);
    var options = new RestClientOptions(baseUrl)
    {
        MaxTimeout = 280 * 1000, 
        RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true,
        ThrowOnAnyError = true
    };
    client = new RestClient(options);
}

public AndroidSmartPOSDeviceResponse Payment(string orderId, double amount)
{
    RestResponse response = null;
    try
    {
        var request = new RestRequest("/v1/transactions/payment", Method.Post);
        request.AddHeader("X-SOURCE", "PaymentSystem");
        var body = new AndroidSmartPOSRequest() { orderId = orderId, amount = amount };
        request.AddParameter("text/plain", body.ToString(), ParameterType.RequestBody);
        response = client.Execute(request);
    }
    catch { }
    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AndroidSmartPOSDeviceResponse>(response.Content);
}
```

Comment: What you describe is how HTTP, the protocol, works. There's no permanent connection. A client can't know whether the connection is down or not if the *server* never sends a response. It can only time out. It's up to your application to handle this. You can use eg Polly to retry failed requests

Comment: In mobile applications you can ask the OS to tell you if its network connection is up or down and retry. Mobile business applications don't use direct calls though, they typically use queues and messaging to ensure *messages* can be sent when the connection is restored. The server is written in a way that can detect and ignore duplicate messages.